# Compare dates and data column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like this:

TABLE 1 - PERSON:

```
m_id | name  |
-------------
22   | jo    |
-------------
77   | john  |
--------------
```

TABLE 2 - AMT_DATA

```
m_id | amt   | activity  |
-------------------------
22   | 100   |    -      |
-------------------------
77   | 300   |    n      |
-------------------------
```

TABLE 3 - STATUS_DATA:

```
m_id  |  status |  s_date       |
```

---

```
 22   |    -    |    01.01.2000 |
 22   |    n    |    01.01.2001 |
 22   |    -    |    01.01.2002 |
 77   |    -    |    01.01.2001 |
 77   |    n    |    01.01.2002 |
```

How can i write a query or procedure that will return me all m_ids which biggest status_data.s_date  for that m_id also have status_data.status = '-'?

I need to get result like this:

```
person.m_id | person.name | amt_data.amt | status |  s_date
------------------------------------------------------------------
     22     |     jo      |     100      |   -    |   01.01.2002
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what `amt` really has to do with the question.  You can just join that in.

One method is:

```
select p.*, status_date, status
from person p join
     (select m_id, max(s_date) as status_date,
             max(status) keep (dense_rank first order by s_date desc) as status
      from status_data
      group by m_id
     ) s
     using (m_id)
where status = '-';
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's (rather verbose) way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select p.m_id,
        P.name,
        A.amt,
        S.status,
        S.s_date,
        Row_number() over (partition by p.m_id order by s.s_date desc) as rn
   From person p
   join amt_data a on p.m_id = a.m_id
   Join status_data s on p.m_id = s.m_id
  Where s.status = '-')
Where rn = 1;
```